# jQuery datepicker dependency based on another element

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to use jQuery's on() event with a datepicker. The flow is user selects a value from a dropdown list, a close event is attached to the startdate which sets the enddate's maxDate to 30 days past the startdate's selectedDate:

```
 $("#ddlRentalTerm").on("change", OnRentalTermChange);

 $("#txtRentalStartDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "Images/iconCalendar0.gif",
    buttonText: "Start Date",
    minDate: -89,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#txtRentalEndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        PopulateNumberOfWeeks(false);
    }
});

$("#txtRentalEndDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonImage: "Images/iconCalendar0.gif",
    buttonText: "End Date",
    minDate: -89,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#txtRentalStartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        PopulateNumberOfWeeks(false);
    }
});



 function OnRentalTermChange(event) {
  var $btnCreatePO = $("#btnCreatePO");
  var $startdate = $("#txtRentalStartDate");
  var $enddate = $("#txtRentalEndDate");
  var selectedDate = new Date();

  var selRental = $("#ddlRentalTerm").val();

  if (selRental === "1") {
    $startdate.datepicker("option", "onClose", BindShortTermDate);
    $startdate.datepicker("refresh");
    $btnCreatePO.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else
  {
    RestoreShortTermStartDate();
    RestoreShortTermEndDate();
    $btnCreatePO.attr('disabled', false);
  }

};

function BindShortTermDate(dateText, instObj)
{
   var $startdate = $("#txtRentalStartDate");
   var $enddate = $("#txtRentalEndDate");
   var selectedDate = new Date(dateText);
   var maxDate = new Date();
   maxDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 30);
   $enddate.datepicker("setDate",maxDate);

  $enddate.datepicker("option",{
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: selectedDate,
    maxDate: maxDate, 
    changeMonth: false, 
    changeYear: false
  });
  $enddate.datepicker("refresh");
}
```

So, I've tried mashing up different examples together but it's not yielding any results. I'm probably making it harder than it needs to be. I tried doing an on( ) on datepicker but it errors. Do I need to destroy the datepicker and recreate it every time I need to change an option? Thanks!

jsFiddle:  [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/willtx/YU9xv/)

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle example

Comment: I added link, thanks. I'm closer now but I need to work on the resetting the datepicker if multiple dates are selected  http://jsfiddle.net/willtx/YU9xv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the option you want to modify then refresh the datepicker.

If you want to bind the event to the datepicker itself use onSelect, if you want it on anything else use the standard $.on

Change an option: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option

refresh: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-refresh

onselect: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

All the best

-Lededje